# SQL vb.net return exception

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have the following query

```
DS = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ADOConnectionString"), CommandType.StoredProcedure, "duMaurier", params)
```

I want to call this in a try

```
Catch ex As Exception
    Return "this"
End Try
```

How do I return a specific message of the error that prevents it running?

Comment: Are you looking for `Return ex.Message`?

Comment: Can you share the full function code please, I can't understand what kind of return you want.

Answer (score 2):

`.message` is a property of the exception.

```
Return ex.message 'This is the string message of the error description
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit nhgrif.  I somehow didn't hit the code option

Answer (score -1):

Like this

```
 Catch ex As Exception
       Throw New Exception("This is may handle exception Error")
 End Try
```

Comment: **Return** and **rethrow** are not the same thing.